# Return to first page of Extjs 4 grid

Tags: extjs, store, paging

I developed Extjs 4 grid with paging. In some event I need to refresh the grid and 
to return to first page.

So far I manage to refresh data but I cannot manage to put to the first page :

```
function RefreshData() {
    var data = globalStore;
    var store = grid.getStore();
    store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: itemsPerPage} });
    var proxy = store.getProxy();
    proxy.url = "";
    proxy.url = getDataWithPageURL;
    grid.getStore().load();

}
```

As you see above,

```
store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: itemsPerPage} });
```

In the line above I try to put to the first row but it's not working?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found how to do it . I need to use loadPage function

Below is fixed function

```
function RefreshData() {
    var store = grid.getStore();
    store.loadPage(1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The initial approach should work also, but little modified:

```
store.load({
    page: 1,
    start: 0
});
```

I had a look in the source code of [Ext.data.Store, method load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/Store.html#Ext-data-Store-method-load) where you can see, that page **and** are overwritten with current values if they are not set in the options.

Unfortunately it does not update the paging toolbar correctly.

Comment: Add store.currentPage = 1; to fix the toolbar.